# Can metal polish damage carbon frames?

Tags: carbon

I have found a [PUROL metal polish](https://www.kemostik.com/neostik-en/supporting-products/purol-80-g-en/) lying on one of my shelves and I was wondering if you can in any way damage a carbon bicycle frame by using this polish on it. The only thing stated on the tube is that, apart from metals, it can also be used on hard plastics, but is not suitable for car polishing. The reason I ask this (despite the paste saying its clearly for metals), is because I think the polish does not even get to the carbon frame - it stops at the level of the paint job on top.

If that is so, I can simply use this to give the paint a bit of a shine and use the polish up.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Carbon frames wouldn’t have a Paint Job as such over the carbon but may have a lacquer protection. Personally with carbon I wipe over with a baby wipe to get most of the dust off, if it’s particularly dirty I will hose down with water and a mild soap and then rag dry.

Answer (score 5):

I would image anything abrasive enough to polish metal would damage the clear coat over paint. Save it for unpainted metallic parts of the bike,things like spokes, crank arms maybe the little chrome bit on the cable housings.

Comment: Agreed. I can’t find much information on Purol. However, Brasso, another metal polish I’ve heard of, contains silica particles as the abrasive agent. Abrasives would indeed damage any paint finish. I’m not sure why Purol says it can be used on hard plastics. Perhaps they meant bare hard plastic?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely never use abrasive finishes on your carbon fibre bike frame.  They're okay on metal components, but its too easy to miss the metal so ideally only polish components while they're off your bike.

Instead, use mild detergents, like biodegradable dishwash, or possibly car wash soaps along with soft cloths.   If you want a shiny frame, look for a wax that is compatible with your frame, and perhaps confirm with the manufacturer that its acceptable.

Honestly hot water and Sunlight works great for me and mine.